# How to access the system color scheme from CSS?

Tags: color, css, html

I would like for the content of a Web page to follow the color scheme of the user's system. For example, if they are using a GTK- or QT-based Web browser, the background of the Web site would match the color of the background color in GTK or QT applications. Is there a way to set the color scheme of the Web page to match the user's system color scheme?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic. Try posting either on [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com)

Answer (score 1):

Only way to do that is by using deprecated CSS2 color value.

In your example background color would be as follows:

```
background-color: Background
```

Here is a full specification from W3.org: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/#css-system

If you write CSS3 or you want your application to be future-proof you shouldn't use these values. Also note that some of them might be available only on Windows.

Comment: huh. I never knew that was even an option. Interesting!